# Hibernate createSqlQuery without getting the blob data from database - "NumberFormatException" on query.list()

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, blob

Shortly ..I have a web app that queries an Oracle database and displays the result on a page. The problem is that I get a `NumberFormatException` when retrieving the data with `query.list()`, this happens only on some tabels. I`ve searched and found out that this is happening because some of my tabels contains BLOB and CLOB data so ..

`Is there any way I can tell hibernate to search on my DB with createSqlQuery(sqlString) without retrieving the BLOB and CLOB data from my DB ?`

Here is a part of my code :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).setFetchSize( Integer.valueOf(nrOfLines) );
    query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
    final List<Map<String, String>> resultQueryList = query.list();
```

NumberFormatException stacktrace:

```
{java.lang.NumberFormatException@2747}Method threw java.lang.NumberFormatException' exception.
detailMessage = {java.lang.String@2875} "For input string: "4294967295""
cause = {java.lang.NumberFormatException@2747}"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4294967295""
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2751} "java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2752} "java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2753} "java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2754} "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData.getPrecisionOracleResultSetMetaData.java:303)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2755} "org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:581)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2756} "org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:508)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2757} "org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:524)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2758} "org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1821)"
{java.lang.StackTraceElement@2759} "org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)" .......
```

I`ve searched a lot but found only how to read blob and clob data from DB... and what I want is exacly the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found out a way to do it. I followed this article http://alessandromigliaccio.blogspot.ro/2010/11/javalangnumberformatexception-for-input.html and added to tomcat 7 the option `-Doracledatabasemetadata.get_lob_precision=false`

Answer (score 0):

Variables that your are declaring, are holding larger values than the data types declared. You should use double or long for the same. that might resolve your problem.